# Run Virtual Domain xampp on mobile

Tags: mobile, xampp, localhost, virtual, domain-name

I have a website running on XAMPP's Apache. I configured my host computer with domain: 127.0.0.1 abc.com, so virtual domain abc.com works on my PC. Now, I want the abc.com domain to work mobile, sharing a LAN. Please help me! I use iphone and how to edit host file on iphone is not feasible.